# Python: Regex finds only part of sought string

Tags: python, regex

The `content` variable contains multiline string:

```
content = """
/blog/1:text:Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur ### don't need this
<break>
text:Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
<break>
text:Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident.

/blog/16:text:Other Lorem ipsum dolor ### SEEKING THIS!!!
<break>
text:Other, really other
<break>
text:Blah blah.
"""
```

I'm trying to find the desired occurrence with the pattern **/blog/16**:

```
re.findall('^(?ism)%s?:(.*?)(\n\n)' % '/blog/16', content)
```

and expecting to get this

```
[(u'/blog/16:text:Other Lorem ipsum dolor ### SEEKING THIS!!!
<break>
text:Other, really other
<break>
text:Blah blah.', u'\n\n')]
```

but getting wrong result (**/blog/1**)

```
[(u'/blog/1:text:Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur ### don't need this
<break>
text:Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
<break>
text:Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident.', u'\n\n')]
```

What is my mistake?

Comment: It is not clear. What is the pattern you are looking for and what is the problem?

Comment: *What is my mistake?*, **Ans:** Your mistake is, you didn't posted sample pattern you want to match.

Comment: Sorry for that, I'm looking for **/blog/16**, but it finds **/blog/1**. Updated the question.

Comment: cant understand what are you expecting on the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you insert the blog text, this part of your regex:

```
/blog/16?:
```

Means "match: `/blog/1` literally; then `6` literally (zero or one times); then `:` literally". Instead, try:

```
(?ism)^/blog/16:(.*?)$
```

This finds all of `/blog/16:` literally at the start of the line, then does a non-greedy search for any characters up to the end of a line (i.e. captures the rest of the text on the line).

You might find [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/oS0hA9) useful for developing and testing regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

When the String replacement is done, your string looks like this

```
^(?ism)/blog/16?:(.*?)(\n\n)
```

Here, `?` means that match the previous pattern 0 or 1 times. So, when the input is `/blog/1`, it matches `0` times and allows the match.

The actual RegEx you are looking for is,

```
import re
print re.findall('(?ims)(/blog/16:.*)(?:/blog|$)', content)
```

**Output**

```
['/blog/16:text:Other Lorem ipsum dolor ### SEEKING THIS!!!\n<break>\ntext:Other, really other\n<break>\ntext:Blah blah.\n']
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot to put the non-capturing group in parentheses. The `?:`. Right now, your `?` says "0 or 1 of the previous element," which means that the 6 is unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you, I thought it related to the whole pattern, not to the last character.